# re-registering a ContainerRegistration in Unity framework without knowing the implementation type

Tags: unity-container

I'm using the Unity Application block as a simple service locator.

I'm registering simple objects as follows:

```
_serviceContainer.RegisterType<ISessionManager, SessionManager>();
```

I would like to re-register that registration in other places in my application by only specifying ISessionManager, that way I don't have interface-implementation logic spread out across my application.

Comment: But you hold the object which inherits ISessionManager?

Answer (score 1):

You should not abuse Unity as a Service Locator. [ServiceLocator is considered an anti-pattern in modern software architecture](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorIsAnAntiPattern.aspx).

You should not register mappings in multiple places in your application. There should be a single [Composition Root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot.aspx) in your application where you wire up the dependency container and resolve the main object of your application. Your container should never appear in your application's code outside the composition root.

If you insist on keeping your architecture the way it is:

```cs
_serviceContainer.RegisterInstance<ISessionManager>(mySessionManagerObject);
```

Should overwrite your registration. But be aware that re-registering that dependency during the runtime of your application might affect other parts of your application.